# Deleting aged postgresql rows with tricky condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have two postgresql tables I need to clean up as part of maintenance. The tables, as described in my Django front-end, are:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    unique = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Reply(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    which_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

I essentially want to delete **all groups where the most recent reply was submitted more than 14 days ago**. What will be the correct sql queries to accomplish that? I'm thinking of:

```
DELETE FROM links_group WHERE id IN (SELECT which_group_id FROM links_reply WHERE "submitted_on" < now() - interval '14 days');
```

But this is missing the logic of *most recent reply*. How do go about with this?

---

Relevant portions of `\d+ links_group;` are:

```
                                                          Table "public.links_group"
     Column     |           Type           |                        Modifiers                         | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_group_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |  
 owner_id       | integer                  | not null                                                 | plain    |              |  
 unique         | character varying(36)    | not null                                                 | extended |              | 
 created_at     | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                 | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "links_group_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_group_unique_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree ("unique")
    "links_group_owner_id" btree (owner_id)
    "links_group_unique_like" btree ("unique" varchar_pattern_ops)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_group_owner_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_reply" CONSTRAINT "links_reply_which_group_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_group_id) REFERENCES links_group(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

Relevant portions of `\d+ links_reply;` are:

```
                                                          Table "public.links_reply"
     Column     |           Type           |                        Modifiers                         | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_reply_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 text           | text                     | not null                                                 | extended |              | 
 which_group_id | integer                  | not null                                                 | plain    |              | 
 writer_id      | integer                  | not null                                                 | plain    |              | 
 submitted_on   | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                 | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "links_reply_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_reply_submitted_on" btree (submitted_on)
    "links_reply_which_group_id" btree (which_group_id)
    "links_reply_writer_id" btree (writer_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_reply_which_group_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_group_id) REFERENCES links_group(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_reply_writer_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (writer_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: Please provide the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements, not just the Python model. The name of the table cannot be `group` for example because that's a reserved word. It might be `"Group"`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Since I didn't manually do `CREATE TABLE` (Django syncdb takes care of it), would it be helpful if I instead provide the output of `/d+ <table name>;`?

Comment: You will certainly get more answers if you provide `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. Most people will just skip over questions where they have to do a lot of initial work to be able to answer. Overall it's less work for the person who asks the question to transform the output from /d+ to `create table` statements, than it is for each and every one of the people trying to answer to do so.

Comment: Thanx for editing the question and supplying the asked info.

Comment: @Lennart The output of `\d+` in postgres, supplies some more info (even more than a create table statement), it has also for example all the referencing (to this table) FKs (from other tables).

Comment: @ypercube, nevertheless I can't use it to create the table. Ideal IMO is an SQLfiddle or `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this (the table and column names may differ, check the actual SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements):

```
DELETE FROM links_group AS g 
WHERE g.id IN 
      ( SELECT r.which_group_id
        FROM links_reply AS r
          -- WHERE r.which_group IS NOT NULL    
          -- not needed, the column is not nullable
        GROUP BY r.which_group_id
        HAVING MAX(r.submitted_on) < NOW() - INTERVAL '14 days'
      ) ;
```

---

Since there is a foreign key from `links_reply` that `references links_group` and does not have an `ON DELETE CASCADE` attribute set, the above will of course fail. To delete from both tables, you either need to run two statements or combine them in one with a modifying CTE:

```
WITH 
  groups_to_delete AS
    ( SELECT r.which_group_id
      FROM links_reply AS r
      GROUP BY r.which_group_id
      HAVING MAX(r.submitted_on) < NOW() - INTERVAL '14 days'
    ),
  delete_replies AS
    ( DELETE FROM links_reply AS r 
      WHERE r.which_group_id IN (TABLE groups_to_delete)
      RETURNING which_group_id
    )
DELETE FROM links_group AS g 
WHERE g.id IN (TABLE delete_replies) ;
```

Comment: Yep, I simplified those. They're actually `links_group` and `links_reply`.

Comment: Need a more information. When I try the above, I get `ERROR:  update or delete on table "links_group" violates foreign key constraint "links_reply_which_group_id_fkey" on table "links_reply"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(251) is still referenced from table "links_reply".
` So maybe your way will need to be changed because, I think, *I'll first need to delete the replies from the groups that I've selected to delete*, and only then delete the respective groups. Correct?

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE scripts for your "Group" (really bad choice of name BTW) and Reply tables.

Comment: Point taken about table naming. Since I didn't manually do CREATE TABLE (Django `syncdb` takes care of it), would it be helpful if I instead provide the output of `/d+ <table name>;`?